# Symfony website with WampServer that displays only the home page

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

I have a Symfony site that works perfectly locally. Now I try to put it on a server with WampServer. Once I launch the virtual host of Wamp, I arrive on the home page of my site (the login page) but once I manage to connect, I get the page :

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) PHP/8.2.6 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev Server at itp-consult Port 80
```

I've tried like said here :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html
too add the symfony/apache-pack bundle and i modified the .httpaccess file but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be modifying the file created by symfony/apache-pack.
The bundle generates a file in the `public/` directory which you should be serving your website from. Make sure you're not serving from the root of your Symfony project. (https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#symfony-deployment-basics)
Also I assume it is a typo but just to make sure : the name of the file should be `.htaccess`, not `.httpaccess`.
Hope this helps.